# Python Regex Excluding Multiple Newlines

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

So I have an issue in parsing text. I'm trying to parse music files, and they are semi-formatted. I am, for example, trying to exclude the choruses from the the lyrics. Most of the time, the formatting looks like this:

```
[Chorus: x2]
Some Lyrics
Some More Lyrics

[Verse]
Lyrics
Lyrics
```

In which case, these two functions can correctly parse:

```
subChorus = re.sub(r'\[Chorus.*?\].*?\[', '[', lyrics, flags = re.DOTALL);
subChorus2 = re.sub(r'\[Chorus.*?\].*?(\n{2,})', '', lyrics, flags = re.DOTALL);
```

However, occasionally the Chorus is the last section of the file:

```
Lyrics

[Chorus]
Some Lyrics
Other Lyrics
```

In such a case, I cannot figure out the correct expression to remove the chorus. If I just do

```
subChorusEnd = re.sub(r'\[Chorus.*?\].*?$', '', lyrics, flags = re.DOTALL);
```

It will work; however, for other files in which the final chorus section is not at the end, it will remove verses that need to be preserved. All Chorus blocks with verses following are separated by at least two newlines. So I came up with this solution:

```
subChorusEnd = re.sub(r'\[Chorus.*?\][^(\n{2,})]*?$', '', subChorus4, flags = re.DOTALL);
```

But it does not work. Can someone explain to me the proper regular expression to get the above statement to work or a better approach at ONLY removing chorus blocks that are at the end of a section of text that will also PRESERVE files in which the final chorus is not at the end.

Comment: So you only want to remove the section if it as the end and retain it if it precedes a Verse?

Comment: In reality I'm combining several of these Chorus-regex substitutions together along with a myriad of other expressions for other nuances to filter the text. The archives of text aren't all formatted the same, so I have about 8 Chorus-text regex substitutions currently. But in this particular case, yes, I would like a function that removes the section if it is at the end and retain it otherwise (The tags often don't say verse and often aren't in [] delimeters, but the Chorus tag should be in a [Chrous.*?] tag)

Comment: @andoni What's your expected output?

Comment: did you mean this `\[Chorus.*?\].*?(\n{2,}|$)` ? https://regex101.com/r/kG6fX5/2

Comment: @AvinashRaj That is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thank you so much. I didn't even think to combine them with an alternation so I wouldn't have the problem with non-ending chorus blocks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to match all the Chorus blocks.

```
\[Chorus.*?\].*?(\n{2,}|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kG6fX5/4)

OR

```
(?!.*\n\n)\[Chorus.*?\].*?$
```

It matches only the `chorus` block which was at the end. Don't forget to enable DOTALL modifier in both regexes.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kG6fX5/3)

Comment: I initially wanted a solution that did not depend on the \n\n at the beginning. Your comment to the question provided the most desired answer and therein, I thought you deserved the accepted answer. Also upon further thought, I believe that in all formattings, the \n\n at the beginning will suffice as well. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome . `(?!.*\n\n)` at the start asserts that the match wouldn't contain any empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using regexes, I would prefer to step over the lyrics line-by-line, and decide whether or not to keep each line using what is basically a crappy finite-state machine:

```
lyrics1 = '''Lyrics

[Chorus]
Some Lyrics
Other Lyrics'''

lyrics2 = '''[Chorus: x2]
Some Lyrics
Some More Lyrics

[Verse]
Lyrics
Lyrics'''

def clean(lyrics):
    result = []
    omitting = False
    for line in lyrics.split('\n'):
        if '[Chorus' in line:
            omitting = True
        if '[' in line and '[Chorus' not in line:
            omitting = False
        if not omitting:
            result.append(line)
    return '\n'.join(result)

print(clean(lyrics1))
print('------------')
print(clean(lyrics2))
```

Result:

```
Lyrics

------------
[Verse]
Lyrics
Lyrics
```

So basically, we flip a flag on if we see a "Chorus" line and stop outputting lines; then, if we see any bracketed thing that *isn't* a "Chorus", we flip the flag back off and resume outputting lines.

I don't know what the actual files you're parsing look like, but it is possible that a strategy like this could prove more fruitful than throwing gargantuan regexes at the problem.

Comment: This surprisingly will work for most formattings. There are some files that are formatted with a Chorus tag and then just two newlines before verses start, without a tag for the verse per-say (That's why I included subChorus2 in my question for how I treat other formattings). Hmm, I could tinker with this though to take care of those edge-cases.

Also, do you happen to know the performance of doing this line-by-line versus regular expressions? I am running this over some 20+ million lines of lyrics.

Comment: @andoni I would suspect that you're going to be primarily limited by the rate at which you can read from and write to disk. The operations here (checking whether one string is `in` another) are fairly quick, assuming your lines are not extremely long.

Answer (score 0):

```
\[Chorus:[^\]]+\][\s\S]*?(?=\n{2}|$)
```

Try this fir all types of chorus.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/77